# Which linux official distribution are less than 100mb?

Tags: linux, docker, debian, busybox

I need some Linux **official** distribution that are less than 100mb for pulling images from docker hub server.
so far I am familiar with debian and busybox. any more official suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking a small linux image with docker, alpine linux is commonly used. The size of alpine linux is only 4MB. You can easily add packages as you need with `apk` command.

https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/

```
$ docker pull alpine
$ docker images | grep alpine
alpine                          latest              4a415e366388        8 days ago          3.99 MB
```